# Are frameworks (e.g., rails) overkill for more simple websites?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, performance

I'm being hired to write a photography website. Basically a gallery layout, links to an online store, etc. I know we use rails for sites like twitter, but would rails be too bulky for this?  Should I go with php instead or are the two pretty much interchangeable and come down to a matter of personal preference?

Comment: Have you considered using a CMS package like Joomla, Drupal or Wordpress, instead of developing everything from scratch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly this is a matter of preference, but there are pros and cons to every language.

I can say that the two are not interchangeable. PHP is almost a catch all language that has tried to implement every concept under the sun. It can be fun to use if you know what you are doing, and are clear about your style and approach to programming, but PHP gives you so much latitude, it can be easy to hang yourself on community examples.

Ruby on Rails is something of a framework in itself, and would be an excellent choice for creating a dynamic site. It is certainly not too bulky, and if your server can run it, the only thing that should stop you from using it, is your comfort level.

The advantage of PHP is that it can be everything to everyone, but ruby presupposes a great deal of experience in programming, and a good understanding of the pitfalls and problems inherent in working with a dynamic language. This is a wonderful thing for experienced programmers, but can be a painful thing for less experienced ones.

If you want to go the PHP route, there are a number a frameworks that can speed up the process, (which is one of ROR's claim to fame). Smarty, Zend and Cake are just a couple examples.

But again, if you are using these frameworks for the first time, the barrier to entry can actually extend your initial development time.

Honestly, a preexisting CMS might be your best choice... though you could go crazy finding a good one, and then figuring out how to bend it to your will. Joomla, Wordpress, ModX, Radiant and Refinery are some examples. (Wordpress being probably the most popular)

Comment: +1 Solid answer. Sometimes a CMS is the best answer, but it's good to note (as you did) that the learning curve for the CMS can be as much as dev time on building a solution from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I never really looked to much into CMS's, I always kind of thought of them as just blog tools. I'm familiar with ruby more than php, but rail's MVC set up was really foreign to me when I first loaded it.

Answer (score 2):

For simple sites, you should try to use an off-the-shelf CMS.
Why rewrite the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

It does come down to personal preference. Here's mine: I would say no, rails is not too bulky for a task like this. Simple websites often lead to more than simple websites. I recently learned Rails and was able to build a simple photo blog in no time at all. It's simple, yes, but it's something I can add to easily as the requirements roll in.

Also, check out Rails + Plugins = CMS (good read): http://rubyredbricks.com/2009/2/24/rails-as-cms

Answer (score 0):

The choice between Rails and PHP (or ASP.Net or Java or ...) is a matter of personal preference.  You just try to find a language and framework that you'll enjoy working in (that you can afford since hosting for different kinds cost different amounts).

If you're thinking that the site is really simple, you should look into a Content Management System (CMS).  A lot of people use [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/) or [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) as a CMS, but there are [tons of options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems) out there.

Answer (score 0):

One point I would add is that I've written a lot of desktop applications. When doing so, I've been very concerned about which libraries I use because it affects the size, download time, and complexity of installing the application.

All that just kind of goes away with a website. As long as the server has all the support code you need, you're good to go.

Use whatever seems easiest for you, or is most readily available. I don't see a right or wrong answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

Although Rails is a "full stack" and quite complete, it won't take up much disk space so having 99% of it just sitting there doing nothing won't actually hurt you.

`In order to stick with the wonderful Ruby language, you could consider Sinatra, or a Rails blog-package like Slate.

I've done a couple of sites in WordPress. You get a lot of polish and premade content management for not much more trouble other than uploading the files, adding a plugin, and choosing a theme. You can throw in a sidebar widget if you feel better having written some code.

Things like Joomla! are more customizable, but Joomla! in particular is kinda large.

These days, I wouldn't touch WordPress or Joomla!, simply because they are in PHP and I've been spoiled by Ruby.

Finally, take a look at what your situation is. Do you have other paying projects ready to start? If so, you will need to pick a reasonably fast approach. But if this is the only thing happening, and you can afford to spend more time on it than it really deserves, you might have other considerations. Perhaps you really think you *should* learn Rails, or some other technology.  Perhaps you want to put package *Xyz* on your resume...